# count records over different values of dates

Tags: date, plsql, count

suppose we have a table that holds events and the date of occurrence, it looks like:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| event_token | date_recorded |
+-------------+---------------+
| event_1     | 06.11.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| event_2     | 06.11.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| event_3     | 06.11.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| event_4     | 06.11.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| event_1     | 05.11.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| event_7     | 05.11.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| event_5     | 04.11.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

what is the best sql (pl sql) statement that returns the total number of events that happened **each day**.
the expected result should looks like:

```
+------------+-------------+
| date       | event_count |
+------------+-------------+
| 06.11.2017 | 4           |
+------------+-------------+
| 05.11.2017 | 2           |
+------------+-------------+
| 04.11.2017 | 1           |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` ... by the way, if the same event happens twice on the same day, do you count it once or twice?

Comment: we count it twice. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The best solution (not just a single SQL) is to have a small DW solution to this. There would be a job running every day (say at 00:00:01), that gathers daily information and summarizes it in a table, that would have Date and Event_Count columns). Each day it would process the data only from the previous day (as it would run on the next). When you query this, you will get summarized data (which is static for previous periods), which will avoid querying the Database and aggregating data over and over again. If you need this data in the middle of the day, there would be a separate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you count each event even if duplicate, you can just aggregate by date and count records.

```
SELECT date_recorded AS date, COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date_recorded;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do count by dates and try to exclude timestamp if you are counting daywise.

```
SELECT to_char(date_recorded,'yyyy/mm/dd') as date, COUNT(*) as event_count
FROM your_table
group by date_recorded;
```